# Как реализовать UI представление чтобы все ui компоненты показывались в пределах одного Actitivty

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment, android-layout

У меня есть идея, но я не знаю как правильно реализовать подобное решение, с UI частью и кодом. Вот как в этом видео. Когда нажимаешь на добавить адрес, выскакивает новое окно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Моё предположение, что мне показывают отдельный fragment или это скрытый lauoyt.
Какой подход использовать чтобы воссоздать подобное ?

Я думаю это делать таким образом:

Я использую карту которая запускается в activity. Если делать навигацию, то нужно карту переносить в отдельный фрагмент и делать этот фрагмент как становой, а уже остальные ui части вызывать через навигацию по средством клика.

Comment: ничего не понял, по-моему обычный переход между двумя активити

Comment: @IR42 вот тут хорошо продемонстрирована работа переходов https://www.flickr.com/photos/194389429@N06/51980280680/in/dateposted-public/

Comment: если имеете в виду там где 3 точки, то это скорее всего ViewPager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Открывается один фаргмнт с картой, по нажатию на кнопку окрывается второй фрагмент с адресом. При вводе адреса он возвращает результат в первый фрагмент. Активити служит только в качестве контейнера в данном случае. ТАк же карта хранит какое то состояние, те данные которые есть или изменены. Вы их туда сюда пробрасываете и дозаполняете так сказать

Второй вариантоткрывается одна активити с картой, потом вторая активити с полями ввода -  но это такое себе решение

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я тоже этого мнения что нужно делать на фрагментах. И здесь возникает вопрос. Как правильно сделать вызов фрагментов. Через `supportFragmentManager` или создать навигацию и вызывать через `findNavController` а передачу данных делать через `MutableLiveData` Схема такова. Activity показывает карты а Fragments A, B, C имеют некий функционал, которые управляют картой

Comment: @SegreiUlanov Навигация - выбор каждого. По сути разницы никакой нет. Передача данных зависит от требований. SetOnFragmentResultListener как по мне здесь подошел бы, но я возможно многого не знаю

Comment: @Poманыч Спасибо за ссылку. Вчера реализовал на `Activity` Гугл карты, а на `Fragments` повесил функционал, всё это через навигацию. Так вот когда я вызываю фрагмент, клики по нему также реагируют и по `Activity` А если вызывать через `supportFragmentManager ` то фрагмент не свернуть. Поэтому вернулся к идеи, что Гугл карты тоже должны быть на фрагменте. А уже через `getChildFragmentManager` вывожу остальной функционал в главный фрагмент

Comment: У вас по идее должно быть все на фрагментах. Активити служит исключительно как контейнер для фрагментов. И при старте активити вы сеттаете сразу Main Fragment какой нибудь и пошло поехало. Повторю - Основная идея этого подхода - активити тупо контейнер у которого в разметке только fragmentContainerViewб все остальное включая тулбары и прочую ересь уже держат  в себе фрагменты